# ibeams ipad application in itunes

Tags: xcode, ipad, itunes

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibeams/id398882202?mt=8

It is a free iPad application in iTunes. Do you know which framework is used in this application.

Comment: Only the author is going to be able to reliably tell you what frameworks were used.  As beryllium points out, these effects can be achieved in many ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS has a lot of different frameworks, and in order to successfully finish app you need to use at least Foundation and UIKit frameworks. That app uses some custom graphics component, so it can use CoreGraphic, Quartz framework or author of this app had wrote his own library for drawing and used it.